# Magento: Add Pinterest "Pin it" button to product detail page

Tags: magento, pinterest

I'm trying to add the ["Pin it" button from Pinterest](http://pinterest.com/about/goodies/) to the pruduct detail pages in our website.

So far I've tried:

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo trim(Mage::registry('current_product')->getProductUrl()) ?>&media;=<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(265) ?>&description;=<?php echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getName(); ?>" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="none">Pin It</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

and

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo trim(Mage::registry(\'current_product\')->getProductUrl()) ?>&media;=<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init(Mage::registry('current_product'), 'small_image')->resize(900,900);?>&description;=<?php echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getName(); ?>" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="none">Pin It</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

With any of these I can get the pruduct's URL and the product's name, but I can not get the product's image. So the post does not work (it needs all 3 items to work: URL, Media and Description)

When I try this:

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://eberjey.com&media;=<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init(Mage::registry('current_product'), 'small_image')->resize(900,900);?>&description;=<?php echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getName(); ?>" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="none">Pin It</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

I can post the product's image, but the URL is not dynamic (I'm just using the absolute URL to the website).

Any ideas on how I could implement this button in my product detail pages?

Answer (score 6):

Most of the answers here don't urlencode() the querystring that's generated for the pinterest link, so I'm a little surprised they've been working - my approach has been a variant of Andrew's that uses http_build_query() to do this for me.

The following code would work when placed inside template/catalog/product/view.phtml:

```
<!--START PIN BUTTON-->
<?php
    $_pinlink['url'] = $_product->getProductUrl();                      
    $_pinlink['media'] = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->__toString() ;
    $_pinlink['description'] = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') . " - " . strip_tags($_product->getDescription());                                                                                   
?>
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?<?php echo http_build_query($_pinlink) ?>" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal"></a>                    
<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
<!--END PIN BUTTON-->
```

I've also noticed that Pinterest strips all html tags from posted descriptions, so there didn't seem much point in passing them through - hence the strip tags on the description.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me:

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo trim(Mage::registry('current_product')->getProductUrl()) ?>&media=<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image') ?>&description=<?php echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getName(); ?>" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="none">Pin It</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

My only concern with this is that it gives the cached image url - rather than a direct one. I do not know how permanent this cached url is. It would seem better to refer to the 'source' rather than the cached version in this instance. But I am not sure....

Comment: It's ok to use the cached image. It's cached for visitors to your store... once it's pinned on Pinterest, Pinterest stores a copy on their CDN. I assume that's what they'll use from then on b/c A) they don't want to rely on websites' links continuing to work, and B) they put it on their super fast media CDN. Thanks for your code - I pasted it verbatim in my view.phtml file:  `app/design/frontend/[my_package]/[my_theme]/template/catalog/product`

Comment: Minor change: Add trims to all the functions. Otherwise, spaces show up preventing the image from displaying & adds a space to the description. My hunch now is that is why @jmanson couldn't get his images to display. `<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo trim(Mage::registry('current_product')->getProductUrl()); ?>&media=<?php echo trim($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')); ?>&description=<?php echo trim(Mage::registry('current_product')->getName()); ?>" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">Pin It</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever try to get current product url in your code? As a result, in product view page, the URL of the product available, just get this url like below :

```
$curProductUrl = $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();

// or we can take product id then use in the code
$_product = $this->getProduct();  
$_id = $_product->getId();  

$_productUrl = $_product->getProductUrl();
$_smallImageUrl = $_product->getSmallImageUrl();
```

Comment: I've tried getting the current product URL, but when I use that code the "Pin it" script does not get the product image.
If I use an absolute URL, like: http://domain.com, then the script gets the product image.
I've also tried '<?php echo $this->_data['urlKey'] ?>' but it still does not work.

Comment: @jmanson if you don't mind, could you please post the wrong and right URL sample in here?

Comment: Did you check the pinit.js? The script wants to url divided by `&`

Answer (score 0):

Try this for adding the image to Pinterest.  It has worked well for me.

```
    $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(150)
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are generating has semicolons after each parameter. Is that intentional? (`...` replaces your `<? php ?>` blocks)

`<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=...&media;=...&description;=..." class="pin-it-button" count-layout="none">Pin It</a>`

`&media;`, `&description;`.

Try removing the semicolons.

Also, if your output is not automatically HTML escaped the ampersands should be HTML entities instead: `&amp;media=` and `&amp;description=`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you have to do:

Copy and paste this code into your themes view.phtml file and your all set:

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?media=<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image'); ?>&description=<?php echo $_product->getdescription() ?>&url=<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal"><img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" /></a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

This will load the product description, image, and link

Sometimes if you put the url later in the dynamic url, it will get stuck loading. So just copy/paste the code above and your done. No customization required.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version of the Pin It button for magento product pages and it works beautifully.
I use the canonical url of the product. For the description: I first insert the name of the product, followed by two breaks (%0A), followed by the description of the product. The htmlentities code for the product description will convert any quotes you have so Pinterest can read it.

```
<!--START PIN BUTTON-->
    <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>&media=<?php echo trim($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')); ?>&description=<?php echo trim(Mage::registry('current_product')->getName()); ?>%20%0A%0A<?php echo htmlentities($_product->getdescription(), ENT_QUOTES) ?>" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal"></a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
<!--END PIN BUTTON-->
```

Comment: I've been using a variation of this that urlencodes the strings and strips all tags (see separate answer) - as far as I can tell Pinterest doesn't accept html tags in the data?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-config="beside" >
<img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_white_20.png" /></a>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   (function(d){
      var f = d.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0], p = d.createElement('SCRIPT');
      p.type = 'text/javascript';
      p.async = true;
      p.src = '//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js';
      f.parentNode.insertBefore(p, f);
   }(document));
</script>
```

But it uses the cached images ...
I'm trying to use the original image path, but with no success until now.

Hope this helps